# how to display two bitmap image on window in C

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, win32gui

i can successfully display single image on window , i'm not sure how to display two images on window. i repeated the same code for difference image but its not working.  here is a code to display single image.

```
 static HBITMAP bmpSource = NULL;
 static HDC hdcSource = NULL;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 HDC hdcDestination;

 //* inside the WndProc()

    case WM_PAINT:

    bmpSource = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,file_path,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
    SelectObject(hdcSource, bmpSource);
    hdcDestination = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    BitBlt(hdcDestination,img_x, img_y, 300, 300, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    breaks;
   //**
```

here is what i'm doing , i have experience in window gui .

```
     static HBITMAP bmpSource = NULL,bmpSource2 = NULL;
 static HDC hdcSource = NULL,hdcSource2 = NULL;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 HDC hdcDestination;

 //* inside the WndProc()

    case WM_PAINT:

    bmpSource = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,file_path,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
    SelectObject(hdcSource, bmpSource);
     bmpSource2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,file2_path,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    hdcSource2 = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
    SelectObject(hdcSource2, bmpSource2);
    hdcDestination = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    BitBlt(hdcDestination,img_x, img_y, 300, 300, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(hdcDestination,img2_x, img2_y, 300, 300, hdcSource2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    breaks;
   //**
```

Comment: You're not releasing the DCs you get with `GetDC`, saving/restoring the old bitmaps when you select with `SelectObject`, nor deleting the DCs you create with `CreateCompatibleDC`. You will very soon run out of GDI resources.

Comment: If `img_x` = `img2_x` and `img_y` = `img2_y`, then you will only see the second image because it would be drawn exactly over the first one. Apart from this, you are leaking too many resources (refer Jonathan's comment above).

Comment: Also, when you say _"its not working"_, what __exactly__ do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show us the code that is not working, so we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Do all painting (i.e. the BitBlt call(s)) after BeginPaint and before EndPaint. Those functions must be called one time only, so don't duplicate them.